# Weird box around text in problem tab vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Weird text selected box in problem tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pECm.png)
Try changing font, profile but nothing changed.
Happened when i type something on keyboard, i think its a shortcut or something like that but i dont know how to fix it.
Please help.

Comment: show a screenshot with more context. is that just the highlighting from what you put in the search / filter input box?